# How does Reddit/Facebook show YouTube previews when crosslinking?

Tags: web

Reddit and Facebook show website previews and previews of the videos when they crosslink to websites and YouTube videos. How do they do this? Is this custom coding on Reddit's side or is there an API/config that website developers can use? I have a custom website with video and I noticed my links come up bare and empty with no previews.

Comment: Open Graph - https://ogp.me

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question. Rather, it is about how reddit and facebook work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YouTube and other sites include information about a page using ['Open Graph'](https://ogp.me) meta tags in the HTML. Eg. on [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1ilCy6XrmI), you will find these in the source:

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="YouTube">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1ilCy6XrmI">
<meta property="og:title" content="WATCH LIVE: ABC News Channel for the latest highlights and 
<meta property="og:image" content="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/W1ilCy6XrmI/maxresdefault_live.jpg">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1280">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="720">
<meta property="og:description" content="ABC News channel provides around the clock coverage of 
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other">
<meta property="og:video:url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W1ilCy6XrmI">
<meta property="og:video:secure_url" content="https://www.youtube.com/embed/W1ilCy6XrmI">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="text/html">
<meta property="og:video:width" content="640">
<meta property="og:video:height" content="360">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="abc">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="abc news">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="australia">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="news channel">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="livestream">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="breaking">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="breaking news">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="news">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="rolling">
<meta property="og:video:tag" content="stream">
```

When a video link is posted on Reddit, they will read the HTML source and gather info such as page title, image preview, **video embed URL** etc.,